# How to read data from `safecopy` image file

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, data-recovery

The hard disk of a ThinkPad with a Windows 7 install was failing, so I tried to recover as much data as possible.

For that I started the ThinkPad with an Ubuntu Live USB, started the terminal and ran `safecopy`. It managed to recover 139 GB of ~149GB from that failing HD.

This is how I ran it:

```
sudo safecopy --stage1 /dev/sdd2 /media/ubuntu/ssd256a/thinkpad.img
```

So now I have an img file on an external SSD, and the original HD cannot be read anymore.

Tried to mount the img file like so:

```
$ sudo mount -o loop thinkpad.img 
mount: thinkpad.img: can't find in /etc/fstab.
```

I can't mount it obviously.

Finally I run `fdisk`

```
parallels@parallels-Parallels-Virtual-Platform:/media/psf/ssd256a$ !31
fdisk -lu thinkpad.img 
Disk thinkpad.img: 139 GiB, 149186150400 bytes, 291379200 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

So there is no info about partition table.

Now I am lost.

How can I read / get the files out of this img file?

Comment: There seems to be nothing wrong. You merely have not provided the `mount` command enough information for it to do it's job. You didn't tell it the (-t) type, nor where in your filesystem you want it to be mounted.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. - So I need to specify the type (`ntfs` in my case, but I suppose `auto` will do as well), and where to mount. But what about the missing partition table?

Comment: So this is what I tried: `parallels@parallels-Parallels-Virtual-Platform:~$ sudo mount /media/psf/ssd256a/thinkpad.img /media/thinkpad/ -t auto` and I get the error message  
`mount: /media/thinkpad: can't read superblock on /dev/loop23.`

Answer (score 0):

`--stage1` means you copied the disk image without attempting to recover any damaged sectors.

Hence the resulting image has holes in some crucial area, and that prevents mounting it.

You should try now with `--stage2`, and if the image still doesn't mount with `--stage3`.